# Read ZIP with umlaut in filename

Tags: ios, objective-c, zip, special-characters

A proper ZIP is encoded with [code page 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437). However this code page is not supported by iOS. Thus I can't extract ZIP files that contain files and folders with special characters like `ä`, `ö` or `ü`.

[Objective-Zip](https://github.com/flyingdolphinstudio/Objective-Zip) and [zipzap](https://github.com/pixelglow/zipzap) convert the filename to `nil`, which makes the file unreadable. [ZipKit](https://github.com/kolpanic/ZipKit) at least converts the umlauts to a question mark. The file can be accessed, but it still looks weird. Is there a way to access the original, CP473 encoded filenames in iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With zipzap you can specify a non-UTF8 encoding for filename interpretation.

In the 8.0 API:

```
ZZArchive* archive = [[ZZArchive alloc]
  initWithURL:URL
      options:@{ ZZOpenOptionsEncodingKey:
                CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(
                  kCFStringEncodingDOSLatinUS) }
        error:nil];
```

In the older API:

```
ZZArchive* archive = [[ZZArchive alloc]
  initWithContentsOfURL:URL
               encoding:CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(
                          kCFStringEncodingDOSLatinUS)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's just a code page.  Each byte is strictly defined as 1 character, so it shouldn't be hard to write up a simple function to convert it to Unicode byte by byte.  All of the code points are listed on the wikipedia page you linked (e.g. 0x81 == \u00FC).